# Check permissions in all the URIs imported from a module in Play

Tags: java, authentication, playframework, module

I'm writing a Play 2.3.2 application in Java. I use a module which has some routes that my application needs. In my route file, I include them with the following statement:

```
->     /recommendation/       recommendationsystem.Routes
```

I need to check permissions on all URIs that start with `/recommendation`. If the user is authenticated, the request is executed, otherwise he is redirected to the home page.

I already have an annotation implementing the action to check the permissions.

How can I make that in Play??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly [intercept](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaInterceptors) all requests within the **Global** class and check if authentication is required for particular resources.

```
import play.GlobalSettings;
import play.libs.F;
import play.mvc.Action;
import play.mvc.Http;
import play.mvc.Result;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    @Override
    public Action onRequest(Http.Request request, Method actionMethod) {
        if (request.path().startsWith("/recommendation") && isNotAuthenticated()) {
            return new Action.Simple() {
                @Override
                public F.Promise<Result> call(Http.Context context) throws Throwable {
                    return F.Promise.pure(redirect("/"));
                }
            };
        }
        return super.onRequest(request, actionMethod);
    }

    private boolean isNotAuthenticated() {
        // put your authentication check logic here
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, this code don't works for me. I thinks that the problem is that all the routes that starts with /recommendation will be redirected automatically to the module (that is written in Scala). How can I solve this problem?? The module cannot have a Global.scala class object.

Comment: The global class should be defined in your main module. Make sure it it placed in the root app directory or set the path within the configuration file: application.global="com.your.package.Global"

Comment: The Global file is on my main project, but all the request that starts with "/recommendation" bypass the onRequest method of my Global.java class. In the other cases the onRequest method was called correctly.